# sqlite timezone now

Tags: python, sqlite, timezone, dst

I am using python and sqlite3 to handle a website. I need all timezones to be in localtime, and I need daylight savings to be accounted for. The ideal method to do this would be to use sqlite to set a global datetime('now') to be +10 hours.

If I can work out how to change sqlite's 'now' with a command, then I was going to use a cronjob to adjust it (I would happily go with an easier method if anyone has one, but cronjob isn't too hard)

Comment: Why cant you just use timezone.now with USE_TZ enabled? Why would you need to modify datetime.now in your db? If everything is UTC then you have an easy conversion for anywhere.

Comment: I'm not using django, and I only want to use it in one area.

Comment: Ah misread sorry. Had too many similar components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what you're asking, but to keep this simple I would say store your dates in UTC, and present them as local time if need be:

```
sqlite> select datetime('now', 'utc');
2012-07-21 09:58:21
sqlite> select datetime('now', 'localtime');
2012-07-21 13:58:33
```

See SQLite's [date and time functions documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: The first part is right. But the second one would end up just getting them back in the localtime of the server (if thats what the OP wants). For client localtime you would probably deliver the UTC to the webpage and let javascript convert it to localtime.

Comment: it's a simple demonstration of how sqlite's functions allow going both ways, nothing more.

Comment: That was my original thoughts, but I have heard that localtime does not support daylight savings. Is this true?

Comment: localtime is basically UTC plus the offset of the local time zone, so if that timezone is EDT (eastearn daylight) then obtaining localtime will add -4 to UTC whereas for EST -5 is added. I'm not sure what you mean by localtime doesn't support daylight saving.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code, I am in Taiwan , so I add 8 hours:

`DateTime('now','+8 hours')`